# In vue-router, how to use beforeLeave

Tags: vue-router

I want to finish some information verify before one component leave.

I've scanned the `vue-router` document: https://router.vuejs.org

But I use `vue-cli`, in my file: router1.vue,

```
console.log(this.$router.beforeLeave) -> undefined
```

How can I use it?

Answer (score 8):

Add this to your `router1.vue`:

```
export default {
  //...
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    // called when the route that renders this component is about to
    // be navigated away from.
    // has access to `this` component instance.
  },
  //...
}
```

for example:

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from , next) {
  const answer = window.confirm('Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!')
  if (answer) {
    next()
  } else {
    next(false)
  }
}
```

And it will be called before this route leave.

ref: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: Welcome, you can select this answer by clicking the check on left. Thank you.

Comment: I clicked it at the first time after I test you code. But my reputation is less than 15...   T T

Comment: @Stark Click the check mark beneath the second arrow